# How to call constructor from one page to other in android?

Tags: android

I have two classes, Class A and Class B. In Class B I created a constructor. In class A I created onresume method. From the onresume method of class A I want to call the class B constructor.
How can I do that? Please guide me regarding this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does class B extends Activity?

Comment: Class B extends Linear layout. It is not an activity.

Comment: Okay then you want to add a linearlayout in your Class A activity view? If would really help if you posted some code of both classes

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `new` object of class `B` in **onResume** of class `A`, it will automatically call the constructor for class `B` for its object.

For example:

```
B obj = new B();  //the 'new' keyword will call the constructor itself
```

Answer (score 0):

If both classes are public and are of same package, you can call constructor of class A in class B by using the code,

```
B objb = new B();
```

Otherwise you need to extend class B from class A.